# Inheritance Casting Using Interfaces Issue

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

I have the following model:

```
public interface IAntiSpam {
    string Name { get; }
    string Text { get; }
}

public interface IAntiSpamSubclass<T> where T : IAntiSpam {
    T Entity { get; set; }
}

public class Comment : IAntiSpam {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public class ForumPost : IAntiSpam {
    public User User { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Name { get return User.Name; }
}

public class ReportedData {        
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public User ReportedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateReported { get; set; }
}

public class CommentReported : ReportedData, IAntiSpamSubclass<Comment> {        
    public Comment Entity { get; set; }
}

public class ForumPostReported : ReportedData, IAntiSpamSubclass<ForumPost> {        
    public ForumPost Entity { get; set; }
}
```

This compiles which I take as a sign I'm on the right path.

Now given a List of ReportedData I need to loop over the data and display the Text property against the reported data.  I could cast the ReportedData to the appropriate type and then access it from there. However I don't wish to do this as I need to be able to add additional types that inherit from ReportedData without having to modify the code which displays the Text property. This is where I figured my interfaces would help.

Here's the code I've tried to run:

```
var reportedData = GetReportedData(); // Returns IList<ReportedData>()

foreach (var data in reportedData) {
    var text = ((IAntiSpamSubclass<IAntiSpam>)data).Entity.Text;
}
```

However this gives the following error at run time:

> Unable to cast object of type 'CommentReported' to type
>   'IAntiSpamSubclass`1[IAntiSpam]'.

I'd appreciate it if someone could help show me what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `IAntiSpamClass<T>` interface is made to be covariant with its type parameter, like this:

```
public interface IAntiSpamSubclass<out T> where T : IAntiSpam {
    T Entity { get; }
}
```

Then this cast will work. Note these changes:

- Added the [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) modifier on the type parameter.
- Removed the property setter.

**Further Reading**

- [Variance in Generic Interfaces (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233059.aspx)
- [Creating Variant Generic Interfaces (C# and Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997386.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I've been meaning to learn about this for a while and this has given me a good kick up the backside. Thanks again much appreciated.